# How do I using QWebPage as a delegate of QListView?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm working on a client for a social network. It is written in Qt & Python.
I need to put the timeline into a `QListView` (think about Twitter or Facebook).

But, QListView can not render rich text, so I use `QTextDocument` as a delegate.

```
class HTMLDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItemV4(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)
        options.text = options.text.replace(" ", "&nbsp;")

        style = QtGui.QApplication.style() if options.widget is None else options.widget.style()

        doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        doc.setHtml(options.text)
        doc.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())

        options.text = ""
        style.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

        ctx = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()

        # Highlighting text if item is selected
        #if (optionV4.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
            #ctx.palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, optionV4.palette.color(QPalette::Active, QPalette::HighlightedText));

        textRect = style.subElementRect(QtGui.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options)
        painter.save()
        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
        doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

        painter.restore()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItemV4(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)

        doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        doc.setHtml(options.text)
        doc.setTextWidth(options.rect.width())
        return QtCore.QSize(doc.idealWidth(), (doc.size().height()))
```

It is works, but it doesn't support all HTML labels.

After a lot of search, I found `QWebView`, it is a fully-functional HTML viewer. I want to use `QWebPage` as a delegate for `QListView`.

So, I tried:

```
class HTMLDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        options = QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItemV4(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)
        options.text = options.text.replace(" ", "&nbsp;")

        style = QtGui.QApplication.style() if options.widget is None else options.widget.style()

        webPage = QtWebKit.QWebPage(self)
        webFrame = webPage.mainFrame()
        webPage.setViewportSize(webPage.mainFrame().contentsSize())
        webFrame.setHtml(options.text)

        #doc.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())

        options.text = ""
        style.drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

        #ctx = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()

        textRect = style.subElementRect(QtGui.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options)
        painter.save()
        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
        webFrame.render(painter)

        painter.restore()
```

But it doesn't work. It just shows blank items.

What wrong did I do?

Or, is there another solution for that situation? I found `setItemWidget()` can put many widget into a item of `QListView`, but it will break Model-View.

Comment: What I notice is that you call `webPage.setViewportSize` before `webFrame.setHtml`, which certainly seems like the wrong way round.  Do you not in any case want the viewport size to be the area that you're going to be painting into?

Comment: How do I set a correct viewpoint size?

Comment: Thanks, I swap them, then I can see the contents. But I don't how to write `sizeHint`, how do I get width or height from `QWebPage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so your original problem as I suggested was that you were calling `webPage.setViewportSize` before `webFrame.setHtml`.

The `sizeHint` is tricky.  `QWebView` doesn't even try, and of course the way web browsers work is that they perform the layout according to the viewport size set by the user.  I would suggest that you need to come up with a sensible value the width yourself.  You should then be able to get the frame height from the `contentsSize`.